# Asp.Net appears to drop the FormsAuthenticationCookie in same domain

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have a pair of websites I am building in Asp.Net.  In development, they are both on my machine.  One is hosted in IIS and one is in IISExpress.  I have configured both websites to use FormsAuthentication, and set the same authentication and httpCookies elements in each web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" timeout="2880" domain=".mydomain"  />
</authentication>

<httpCookies domain=".mydomain" requireSSL="false"/>
```

However, after a standard `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` , the second site cannot read the .ASPXAUTH cookie from the first.  It CAN read the same Asp.Net_SessionID cookie from the other website.  So, one cookie is being passed across applications, but the second is not.

Additionally, when the debugger is attached to the second application and it receives the redirect from the from the first site, the Chrome debugger shows both cookies, Fiddler reports that both cookies were transmitted, and the Response.Headers["cookie'] contains the .ASPXAUTH cookie.

How can I effect this cross-application sign-on?  In production, these two sites will answer on separate sub-domains.

Comment: Your scenario is not quite clear. You say that one site is hosted on IIS and the other on IISExpress. But those web servers cannot listen on the same port, right? So you have on site on `http://mydomain:80` and the other on `http://mydomain:8080`, right? In this case you cannot share any cookie at all as you are violating the same origin policy.

Comment: No no...  actually they are sharing the Asp.Net_SessionID cookie.  I CAN see that from the second site, and I can access the contents of the session.  The FormsAuthenticationTicket is not being passed, even though it is marked as a Domain cookie

Comment: are you using an out-of-proc session provider? How are you sharing session information between 2 different ASP.NET applications which are of course different processes?

Comment: Ah yes... I am using SqlServer as my session provider.  Thus, the SessionId passed (in cookie) from one site to the other, enables the contents of the session to appear.  I don't understand why the FormsAuthenticationTicket ".ASPXAUTH" is NOT being passed, but SessionId is...

Comment: I have also reviewed the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx and not found much luck

Comment: that's weird, as I have the exact same scenario working in production without any problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6593/discussion-between-jeff-fritz-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem.

IISExpress and IIS use separate MachineKey values, even though they are originating on the same physical machine.  To solve my problem, I generated a MachineKey entry at http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey and dropped the same `MachineKey` element into all participating application's web.config files.

Thanks to Robert Smith @smithrobs on Twitter for suggesting I check this line of the problem.